# Django + Heroku - Debug = False issues

Tags: python, django, debugging, heroku, web

I've been working on a website for a while now (Django/Python on Heroku). I usually have debug = true while developing, but now when I set to false I get 'application errors' from Heroku. My logs inform me that the issue is a "Request Interrupted" (H18, sock=backend).

I understand that this means that I have an error somewhere in my code, but for the life of me I cannot figure out where.

I'm also having a hard time finding an efficient debugging work-flow when Debug=False. I have logentries and NewRelic for error monitoring on the Heroku app, but NewRelic reports 0 errors while logentries only gives me the default heroku-app error logs.

I cannot possibly show you all my code (also I won't), so I realize that it'll be difficult for anyone to pinpoint my exact problem - therefore I am more asking in general terms.

I know that all URLs need to end with a slash, and that the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting is required - but what else can result in these errors when debug = false ?

Oh please note that EVERYTHING works as intended when debug is true.

I'm running Django version 1.7 with Python version 2.7.6.

These are the 3rd party apps that I use:

- Grappelli (loaded before default Django apps)
- gunicorn
- storages
- compressor
- collectfast
- haystack
- bootstrap3
- robots
- sorl.thumbnail
- django_countries
- django_wysiwyg
- validatedfile
- colorfield
- cookielaw

Comment: Try setting `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False`, or better yet, set it to `True` with `DEBUG = True`, I suspect that's the culprit. `COMPRESS_ENABLED` defaults to `not DEBUG`, so it will behave differently with `DEBUG = False` by default. Some other third-party app might have similar behaviour. Have you double-checked your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting for errors?

Comment: I had already tried playing around with COMPRESS_ENABLED a lot actually, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I apparently discovered the culprit. I was also using [django-htmlmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin), and for whatever weird reason that apparently caused my issues. I removed it and everything worked fine regardless of the debug setting. Yay!

I don't have the insight to say *why* django-htmlmin was causing these issues, although I suspect it might be incompatible with Django 1.7 or Django-Compresser.